# Checking if a string is a palindrome

Tags: performance, c, comparative-review, palindrome

This is the code for checking if a string is a palindrome. The execution time, for sample cases, is 0.40358 seconds. What must be done to increase the performance?

```
int main(){
    int c,flag = 0;
    char *ch, *h;
    ch = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*101);
    h = ch;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        *ch = c;
        ch++;
    }
    ch--;
    while(ch>=h){
        if(*ch-- != *h++){flag = 1; break;}
    }
    flag == 1?(printf("NO")):(printf("YES"));
}
```

This is the code with an execution time of 0.4017 seconds for same test cases:

```
void main()
{
    char a[100],b[1000];
    int n,i,j=0,f=0;
    scanf("%s",a);
    n=strlen(a);
    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        b[j]=a[i];
        j++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==b[i])
        {
            f++;

        }
    }
    if(f==n-1)
    {
        printf("YES");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO");
    }
}
```

Why is the former slower than the latter? Are the library functions faster?

Comment: How did you measure the times?  Have you considered that 0.0018 seconds could be in the margin of error for your time measurement?

Comment: Your second example uses void main -- always use int main.

Comment: @ringzero "always use int main. " --> C specifies that an implementation is allowed other `main()` signatures.  It is doubtful that changing the signature affects OP's goal of "What must be done to increase the performance?"

Comment: @chux Posting a program on CodeReview invites comments about any aspect of the code. A program which uses void main -- rather than int main -- is of questionable quality. The OP's concern about speed is perhaps misplaced considering the well-known advice: first make it work, then make it right and finally make it fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version is the better approach and as already pointed out, what you measure here is outside the precision of measuring, so performance-wise, these solutions are equal.

Now some suggestions how to improve the code of the first version:

- You allocate your buffer in a needlessly complicated way:

  ```
  ch = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*101);
  ```

  first of all, there's no point of casting `void *` in C, it is implicitly convertible to any data pointer type. Casting it could even hide a bug, see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/2371524) for details. Then, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1`, so you can leave it out. The whole line would then look like:

  ```
  ch = malloc(101);
  ```

  But why should you use dynamic allocation at all if you use a fixed size? Just use an array, similar to the code in your second version:

  ```
  char buf[101];
  ```

  Note I also suggest a different name here: `buf` tells the reader that this is a buffer for something (input in your case), while `ch` would make you think it's the name of a variable holding a single character.
- You happily overflow your buffer:

  ```
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
      *ch = c;
      ch++;
  }
  ```

  You should never write code like this. There are functions for reading a limited amount of data, and as your buffer has a fixed size, you should use such a function, e.g.:

  ```
  memset(buf, 0, 101);
  size_t n = fread(buf, 1, 101, stdin);
  char *ch = buf + n;
  ```

  Without knowing your exact requirements, I *guess* you didn't intend to analyze "multi-line" palindromes, so using `fgets()` would be even a better choice:

  ```
  if (!(fgets(buf, 101, stdin) && *buf)) exit(1);
  size_t n = strlen(buf);
  if (buf[n-1] == '\n') buf[--n] = 0; // strip newline if present
  char *ch = buf + n;
  ```

  This is still close to your initial code, in practice, I'd use a larger buffer just to be sure and also define the buffer size as a macro, so I can change it without risking to introduce an overflow bug.
- Regarding your second version, using `scanf("%s", ...)` will also overflow any buffer. A safe way of using `scanf` for reading in a fixed size buffer would be `scanf("%100s", buf)` if buf has a size of 101. I'd suggest not to use `scanf()` for this purpose at all. -- thanks for the comment!
- A minor point since you are interested in performance:

  ```
      flag == 1?(printf("NO")):(printf("YES"));
  ```

  `printf()` must scan its first argument to know whether there are more arguments to follow, this is unnecessary for a constant output, so just use `puts()` if you want an automatic newline or `fputs()` to avoid the newline. In this case, `puts()` will be fine:

  ```
      flag == 1?(puts("NO")):(puts("YES"));
  ```
- And as a general advise: Try to find better variable names that really describe the *meaning* of the variable, like instead of a `flag`, how about a `isPalindrome`?

**Suggested improved version** which also improves on readability:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024
char buf[BUFSIZE]; // 1K buffer with static storage

int main(void)
{
    if (!(fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin) && *buf))
    {
        // reading a line from stdin failed, give up
        return 1;
    }

    size_t n = strlen(buf);
    if (buf[n-1] == '\n') buf[--n] = 0; // strip newline

    char *front = buf;
    char *back = buf + n;

    int isPalindrome = 1;
    while (back > front)
    {
        if (*--back != *front++)
        {
            isPalindrome = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    puts(isPalindrome ? "YES" : "NO");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer; you might want to point out that `scanf("%s", &buf)` also has an overflow problem, fixable with `"%*s", sizeof buf - 1, &buf`.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't have a closer look at the second example.

Comment: @TobySpeight but I don't think a `*` would work as expected, as I read the `scanf()` manual, this just discards the result of the conversion...

Comment: I was thinking of `printf()` where the `*` says that the field width is to come from arguments.  Sorry about that!  There's a bit of a dance to get safe `scanf()`: [How to prevent scanf causing a buffer overflow in C?](//stackoverflow.com/a/1621973)

Comment: A `malloc()` followed by a `memset()` to set all zeroes can be replaced by a single call to `calloc()`. You don't need that in your final version, but it might be worth pointing out on the way to there.

Comment: `if (!fgets(buf, 101, stdin)) exit(1);
size_t n = strlen(buf);
if (buf[n-1] == ....`is the beginning of an exploit.  What if `n== 0`?  It is not too hard to have the first character of `fgets()` to be a null character.

Comment: 1) "`printf()` must scan its first argument to know..."` is weak advice.  Good compiles will emit the same code with `printf("NO")` and `fputs("NO", stdout)`.  2) `puts("NO")` is not even equivalent functionality as it appends a `\n`.

Comment: " What must be done to increase the performance?" and `memset(buf, 0, 101);` is a contradictory.  No need to zero the entire buffer concerning speed.

Comment: `if (*--back != *front++)` is UB with input `"\n"`.

Comment: `buf[--n] = 0;` is not needed. Only `n--`.

Comment: `fgets()` called with n>1 can never return non-`NULL` on an empty string. The `memset` isn't in my final code, but would be needed with `fread()` for OPs original semantics. Counting on the compiler for one particular optimization is *bad advice*. `*--back != *front++` is absolutely fine, even on a 1 character input, the one character is compared to itself and the pointers switch places (pointing to it resp. to the terminating `0`). Only your last comment is correct, but i sticked to the pattern of *stripping* the newline.

Comment: @chux forget my complaint about your *first* comment, you probably meant `stdin` could actually deliver a 0 byte, yes, that's true, so I'm adding a little check here.

Comment: When `input` is `"\n"`, `n` becomes 0 at `char *back = buf + n;` then `back == buf`.  `--back` is decrementing a pointer to `buf` before its beginning, which is UB.  `back >= front` --> `back > front` nicely prevents that.

Comment: "The memset ...  would be needed with fread() for OPs original semantics" is curious `memset(buf, 0, 101);` before `size_t n = fread(buf, 1, 101, stdin);` has what benefit?  It does not insure `buf` is a string, nor is data after the `n` bytes read accessed.

Comment: @chux the `>=` was a mindless copy&paste error from the original code working in a different fashion .. spotted only after your comments. It wasn't intended to be there, so I couldn't quite understand where you see a problem with the *next* line.

Comment: My comment was based on what was originally  posted, not on what you intended.  IAC, the improved post prevents the UB.

Comment: Interesting lead _null character_ with `if (!(fgets(buf, 101, stdin) && *buf)) exit(1);`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't really call a difference of 1% slower or faster. You should consider that both codes have exactly the same performance.

The only explanation for a speed difference between those two applications comes from the malloc (which is slightly slower than an array).

IMO, first code is better than second; the second one is quite hard to get (you are basically reversing a string, then comparing the reversed string with the normal one). I actually had to read the code 3 times to understand what was done.

About code review in itself:

- First code sample:

  You should indent your code in a consistent manner.

  ```
  int c,flag = 0;
  char *ch, *h;
  ```

  Those variables are poorly named; `flag` could be replaced by `is_palindromic`, `h` could be `string_start`/`str_start`/`str`, and `ch` `string_from_end`/`string_reverse` etc....

  ```
  while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
  ```

  It's usually a good idea to separate comparators and equal sign from their operands, so it'd be something like this:

  ```
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
  ```
- Second code sample:

  ```
  char a[100],b[1000];
  int n,i,j=0,f=0;
  ```

  Same as before, you should also avoid declaring 4 variables on the same line (especially considering you have both initialized and non-initialized variables).

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing all the characters of two the arrays:

```
for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(a[i]==b[i])
    {
        f++;

    }
}
```

Instead, you can do something like this :

```
isPalin = 0 ;
n= strlen(charArray)
for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)
{
    if( charArray[i] != charArray[j] )
    {
        isPalin = 1 ; 
        break ;
    }
    j-- ;
}
puts(isPalin? "YES" : "NO" ) ;
```

You only use one array and only traverse till (n/2-1) position of the array compared to your example. Execution time comes down to 0.822 secs.